# Why does PHP not GET the form input from this HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadFile">      
<label>Select files to upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" /><br>
IF you didn't add tags in the image titles your can add them here "," seperated eg tagone,tagtwo,tagthree,tagfour <br> 
<input type="text" name="Tags"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="btnSubmit"/>
</form>

<?php

$tags =  $_GET["Tags"];

    foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
    $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

    if(empty($temp))
    {
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_GET` superglobal is populated by data from the query string of the URL.

A form, with `method="POST"`, will put data from the form controls in the request body, not the query string. (Data in the query string of the `action` will still be there).

You need to read it from `$_POST` (except for files which are in `$_FILES`).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are able to try in below.

$tags =  $_POST["Tags"];

Comment: because the <form method ="post" > , you should write $_POST["tags"]. Method post is for send your data to php and php will be proccess to add in database